# Changing Declared Variables in Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, variables

I have been trying to change the values of variables inside of an array. I thought that the code below would produce the result of

```
1, 1
```

but really it produces

```
1, 0
```

indicating that `a` was never changed. So my question is this: why doesn't the code below change the value of `a`, and how can I rewrite it to do so?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c[2] = { a, b };
    c[0]++;
    std::cout << c[0] << ", " << a;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why doesn't the code below change the value of `a`, ...

Because a copy of `a` and `b` is taken to initialize the raw array.

> ... and how can I rewrite it to do so?

You cannot use a raw array of references to do that ([won't compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b33448f156e2dd3a)), but using [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) works fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    std::reference_wrapper<int> c[2] = { a, b };
    c[0]++;

    std::cout << c[0] << ", " << a << '\n';
}
```

See a [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a37869d162806a2)

Answer (score 1):

The initialization `int c[2] = { a, b };` copies the value `a` into the first element of the array `c`.

From this moment on, `a` and `c[0]` are two distinct values in the memory space of your application.

Changing one will not affect the other.

If you wish to change this, you should either use a `reference_wrapper` as suggested by other answers or use `shared_ptr`:

```
int main()
{
    auto a = std::make_shared<int>(0);
    auto b = std::make_shared<int>(0);
    std::shared_ptr<int> c[2] = { a, b };
    (*c[0])++;
    std::cout << *c[0] << ", " << *a;
}
```

**Note**: Using `shared_ptr`-s makes sure that even `a` goes out of scope, the value inside the vector stays valid.